# Problem in solving ODE from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem in solving a type of ODE from NDSolve. Specifically I want to know the solution at time T (say T=50). The number of differential equations increases at each iteration. This equations involves one parameters, and I want the solution of the differential equations at each iteration.

```
T = 10;
nu = 0.2;
n = 5;

vars = Table[Subscript[x, j][t], {i, n}, {j, i}];

eqns = Table[{
    Subscript[x, j]'[t] == Subscript[x, j][t] (1 - Subscript[x, j][t] - nu Sum[Subscript[x, k][t] Boole[k != j], {k, i}]),
    Subscript[x, j][0] == 0.3},
  {i, n}, {j, i}
 ];
```

The variable `eqns` gives exactly the process of iteration that I need

```
sol = NDSolve[eqns, Table[Subscript[x, j], {i, n}, {j, i}], {t, 0, T}, DependentVariables -> vars]
```

But Mathematica gives the message

> NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation. >>

I don't understand how to fix it. I believe it violates some operation NDSolve.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do, but I can say with reasonable confidence that your `NDSolve` arguments are invalid.  I recommend that you state clearly the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The sentence "The number of differential equations increases at each iteration" isn't clear.  Do you want to increase `n` at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting to solve ODEs one through five in sequence, one way to do so is

```
GraphicsGrid[{Table[s = NDSolve[eqns[[n]], vars[[n]], {t, 0, T}];
    Plot[Evaluate[vars[[n]] /. s], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All], {n, 5}]}, 
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Alternatively, the solutions can be presented in a single plot.

```
Show @@ Table[s = NDSolve[eqns[[n]], vars[[n]], {t, 0, T}];
    Plot[Evaluate[vars[[n]] /. s], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All], {n, 5}]
```

[image]

Not surprisingly, all curves for each value of `n` coincide.